# S3 Amazon Web Service Permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there any possibility to grant permission on particular name of folder, so that all folders with that particular name are public?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sure ! Just specify your path in the resource section part of your policy document.

Example  :

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"sid123",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/mydirectory/subdir/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Full documentation is here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-arn-format.html